# TSQL, update col a = 0 set all the values for col a =0 in the table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-update

I am trying to find way to do below in SQL table, where a is bit data type

- if update col a = 0 all the other values for col a in the table should be updated to 0 and
- if update col a = 1 all the other values for col a in the table should be updated to 1.

Comment: are you saying that you will update it or if any update occurs this should happen?

Comment: TSQL as in Sybase or SQL Server?  Version too, pls.  And what's the scope of the update?  Otherwise all the col_a values will be either zero or one.

Comment: Wow, maybe its just me but I can't make sense of the question.  Maybe a description of the table columns and some sample rows would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the INSTEAD OF trigger. It's a [Highlander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2886362#2886362)-type trigger, meaning there can only be one of it on a table (for every operation).

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTable_SetBitColumn ON MyTable INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS BEGIN
  UPDATE MyTable
  SET BitColumn = i.BitColumn
  FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM inserted) i
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to toggle all values for that column? If so:

```
UPDATE table
SET BitColumn = 1 - BitColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
UPDATE mytable SET a=1
```

or

```
UPDATE mytable SET a=0
```

Comment: Its SQL Server 2008, and it should be like if I update column a = 0 all the values should become 0 without me doing manual UPDATE mytable SET a=1 or 0 like can I use trigger ?

Comment: Its SQL Server 2008, and it should be like if I update column a = 0 for just one row all the rows for a should become 0 without me doing manual UPDATE mytable SET a=0 or 1 like can I use trigger ?

Answer (score 0):

If all the rows in the table will have the same value then don't store this column in this table. Store it in another table with 1 row. You can then cross join onto the single row table when doing your queries.